# Loading score for a game

Tags: java, file, save, bufferedreader, filereader

In the game that I am currently working on I want to make it so that when you start the game you get the previous score you had befor you quit. I have already made a save file for the score with this code.

```
                try{
                    File getScore = new File("Score.dat");
                    FileOutputStream scoreFile = new FileOutputStream(getScore);
                    byte[] saveScore = score.getBytes();
                    scoreFile.write(saveScore);
                }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

                }catch(IOException ex){

                }
```

The score is displayed as a String so therefor upon start the game have to get the score inside the .dat file as an string so that I can equal the score string to the string that was generated upon start. I have tried using the code shown below.

```
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Score.dat"));
            score = br.toString();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){

        }
```

But when I use that code I get this error message.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java.io.BufferedReader@313159f1"
```

Comment: What is `score`s type?

Comment: @TheMerovingian It's a `String`, but everytime I update it I change it to an `int` add 10 to the `int` and then turn it back to a `String`

Comment: 1. You should close the `FileOutputStream` by call `scoreFile.close()`; 2. You should use the `br.readLine()` instead of `br.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `br.toString()`, it calls the `toString()` method from the class object on your BufferedReader object. So it prints the memory adress of your buffered object :

```
public String toString() {
           return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
 }
```

That's why you get a `NumberFormatException` because you can't assign a `String` to `score` (which I suppose is an `int` variable).

Furthermore, you are absolutely not looking for that because you want the text stored in your file. If you want to read a single line from your buffer you just have to do this  :

```
 String line = br.readLine();
    int value = Integer.parseInt(line);
```